# nothing added to commit but untracked files present

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-artifacts

I am able to add one separate file , make changes and the change is reflected in Team explorer in visual studio. I am able to push file to repos successfully. But When I try to add one folder , the files and subfolder present under the parent-directories are not reflected for  changes in visual studio.

Kindly let me know if I should change any settings before making this commit
Step By Step Process
1. I am creating new repositary in azure artifacts
2. I am opening my visual studio --> Team explorer --> connect to server .
3. I have connected to my server and cloned it to my local . local repo is created
4 Now I copy my workspace and paste it in local repository. My workspace contains many folders and sub folders are present in the workspace.
5. In visual studio --> changes --> I am able to see only main folders or parent directory. (sub folders and files available in subfolders are not available in changes).
6. I committed and pushed the code.
7. Now in artifacts in repos , only main folder or parent directory is present, sub folders are not available.

Comment: Can you add some additional details of where and how you are adding files (both for when it works and when it doesn't). Are you doing it within the file system, within visual studio, etc.? Add as much detail as possible to give us an idea of what exactly is happening

Comment: Which kind of version control are you using? Git or TFVC?

Comment: I am using GIT for version control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description for detail steps, there is nothing business with [Azure Artifacts.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/?view=azure-devops)  Which used for Code once and share packages across your organization. Host your private Nuget, npm, and Maven packages with Azure Artifacts for more reliable, scalable builds.

Are you just talking about version control. There should be something wrong with your source control binding.

Do not directly copy and past files.

Suggest you to follow the official tutorial to [add files in server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=azure-devops).